# How to retrieve a string with spaces and fill it with characters on an android application

Tags: java, android

I am retrieving a string input from a user on an Android application as a search term to apply to a API.  However, the API does not accept spaces in between search terms e.g "malaria and humans".  How can I best convert this string to : "malaria%20and%20humans"?  This is what is required should you want to make the search with these terms.

Comment: google ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130056/urlencoder-encode-and-a-whitespace

Answer (score 1):

You use [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Example

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("hello world", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: There are lots of this type of questions on stackoverflow, you should make comment for this type of questions.

Answer (score 0):

[Encode](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) your String before using it as a URL.